# cannot allocate vector of size 2928.7 Gb

Tags: r

I downloaded the latest version of R 4 and since  I have this error message:

> cannot allocate vector of size 2928.7 Gb

THE CODE:

```
regfit.hyb<-regsubsets(salary~.,data=ndata[train,],method="seqrep",nvmax = 14)
reg.summary <- summary(regfit.hyb)
bestCp<-which.min(reg.summary$cp)
```

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Thank you for any help